# Why Impala generates multiple files for one insert statement

Tags: hadoop, impala

It is supposed that only one file should be generated for a single "insert...select" statement, while 20 files are generated in my case. How can I reduce the result into one single file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are small, you can use `SET NUM_NODES=1` to force all of the data through a single node, as noted in the [documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_parquet.html#parquet_compacting_unique_1).